# How to set an `imagesLoaded` state within useAppIsReady in App.tsx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation

I have a react native app. I have a hook `useAppIsReady` that contains a check for whether images have been loaded yet located in my App.tsx.

The way it works is I have state in my context `numberOfImagesLoaded`. I have multiple images loaded within Home. When an image loads, `numberOfImagesLoaded` gets incremented by 1, and once it reaches a specified number, `appIsReady` gets set to `true`.

The problem is that I can't use `useAppIsReady` within my `App.tsx` since `numberOfImagesLoaded` is located within my context, and The `return` statement that contains my whole app wrapped in context is defined after `useAppIsReady` gets called, so I'm forced to place `useAppIsReady` inside my `Home` component instead, which is suboptimal. How can I make `useAppIsReady` work in App.tsx?

I don't want to define the `numberOfImagesLoaded` state in my App.tsx because it will be a pain to pass down through props.

useAppIsReady

```js
const useAppIsReady = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  // If all images are loaded

  const imagesAreLoaded = context.numberOfImagesLoaded > 5;

  if (imagesAreLoaded && !appIsReady) {
    setAppIsReady(true);
  }

  return appIsReady;
};
```

App.tsx

```js
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {

  // useAppIsReady() won't work since context has not yet been defined

  const appIsReady = useAppIsReady();

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<AppParamList>();

   useEffect(() => {
    const prepare = async () => {
      if (appIsReady) {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    };

    prepare();
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <AppProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
          >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="MyQueues"
              component={MyQueuesScreen}
            />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either lift the `appIsReady` state up (e.g. into `<AppProvider>`) where you have access to the `numberOfImagesLoaded` state and use it there.

Finally, you pass `appIsReady` to a child component or provide it via context, where you use and handle the ready state.

Here's an example:

```js
const AppProvider = () => {
...
const [numberOfImagesLoaded, setNumberOfImagesLoaded] = useState(0);

const appIsReady = useAppIsReady(numberOfImagesLoaded);

return (
   <YourContext.Provider value={{numberOfImagesLoaded, appIsReady}}>
      {children}
   </YourContext.Provider>
);
}
```

```js
const useAppIsReady = ({numberOfImagesLoaded}) => {
   ...
   useEffect(() => {
      // your ready logic
   },[numberOfImagesLoaded]);

   return appIsReady;
}
```

`App` or whichever needed component can use the context and access `appIsReady`.

Comment: My question may have been unclear. `App.tsx` is the highest level in my app it is the entry point. Moving `appIsReady` into context would not be moving state up it would be moving state down. My problem is that `appIsReady` is defined at too high a level, at the entry point `App.tsx`, that it cannot access context for `numberOfImagesLoaded` and so im forced to use `appIsReady` in a lower component e.g. `Home`, instead of `App.tsx`, where I want to use it.

Comment: Where is your `AppContext` being provided? Assuming that you provide it in `AppProvider`, `App.tsx` actually isn't your highest level, because the `numberOfImagesLoaded` is being defined somewhere higher.